# Architecture - Multiple pages in GWT means multiple modules?

Tags: gwt, architecture

This is more a design/architecture question.

I am thinking of a web app and I want to use GWT (I used it long ago and I am back to it, so just assume I am a rookie). Like many apps, it will have many entry points, the obvious being signin, lostpassword, signup, etc. More will be added.

To keep code clear & clean, would you:

1. Make a separate project for each entry point, or:
2. Have a global project and try to have multiple  (I don't know if this is feasable), or:
3. Have a single project, many services and manage "user entry points" via the History / Bookmark mechanism...

I am tempted by the third option, but I admit I have not pushed it yet to production, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the modules don't need to communicate with each other I suggest to go for 1).

It's easier to work on a small modules with GWT. Since incremental compilation isn't available yet, you can save a lot of compile time by breaking your app into modules.

Code splitting is a helpful feature, but its purpose is to break-up the app into small pieces, which is best done after the code is written and more-ore-less stable. If you can have multiple modules from the start, that's easier.

If you need to share common code consider using GWT-compatible libraries instead of merging projects.

Comment: Well, nothing is really "completely independent"... I like your solution when there is quasi independent modules (e.g. login, lost password, register), but as soon as they start sharing stuff, what is the limit? I am very naively asking the question...

Comment: When in the browser, two GWT modules can not communicate with each other easily. The workaround is to use JSNI methods, write data to the DOM, and have the other module read from there. Not ideal isn't it ? Modules can communicate through a common server-side session or cookies but if they need to share data through the DOM forget about it :-). Pay attention to put common views/widgets/logic into a library that modules can share. Note that you can have multiple modules in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest option 3. It would seem unusual for the different entry points to be so different that you don't want to share a lot of code. The only issue might be if you main app has huge client side code and you don't want to load all that for "lost password" etc. In that case you could use code splitting.

We have done it like this and all is fine. We use spring security for the servlet so had to do some fiddling with RequestFactory to use a different URL for registration etc but apart from that it has been pretty smooth.

Comment: Thanks - does that mean that all UI code will be transferred, regardless of the need?

Comment: Yes, unless you use http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html  I've never needed to use it so can't vouch for it myself.